# Visual Studio 2015 not showing snippets of documentation on hover

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Out of the blue sky my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise stopped showing documentation about .NET classes. It does not show explanations / documentation about the classes / properties / methods when hovering them or when accessing them with the dot operator.

Here is an example:

[image]
 -

The pop-up should have said something about what a `MatchCollection` represents ...

How can I enable VS 2015 to show me the snippets of documentation in the pop-up?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to reset the settings of VS ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms241273.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Hi. I have not. I'm afraid it will reset settings for TFS that I have had a hard time configuring.

Comment: The reset has nothing to do with your TFS config.

Comment: Allright. I tried it. It works only on a new project. So I think my solution / project has problems that block this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restore the documentation feature I did this:

1. remove the `proj` from the `sln`
2. delete local files and also the binded files on TFS
3. create brand new project, add it into the `sln`
4. add content from the old `.cs` files into the new project and new references
5. Clean solution and Rebuild All

Now it works again. Weird stuff.

EDIT: after checking with other devs in the office, this issue (of not having documentation available on tooltip) is also present in projects that are targeting .NET 2.0. Don't know how that gets fixed though.